# How to set a program's command line arguments for GHCi?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Suppose some Haskell file is executed with

```
runghc Queens.hs gecode_compile
```

Now, this fails, and I want to debug it with `ghci`. How do I pass the option `gecode_compile` into the program, so `getArgs` will read it correctly?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 80, accepted):

You can also set the command line arguments in ghci

```
ghci> :set args foo bar
ghci> main
```

or

```
ghci> :main foo bar
```

Comment: yeah, too bad the shortcut doesn't turn on trace

Answer (score 25):

You can use the [`System.Environment.withArgs`](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0-latest/html/libraries/base-4.3.1.0/System-Environment.html#v%3awithArgs) function to execute `main` with your desired arguments.

Here's an example session (irrelevant details elided):

```
$ ghci
GHCi, version 7.0.3: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
Prelude> import System.Environment
Prelude System.Environment> let main = getArgs >>= mapM_ putStrLn
Prelude System.Environment> withArgs ["hello", "world"] main
hello
world
```

Answer (score 14):

You can use the `:set` command:

```
Prelude> :set args whatever
```

This will mean that `getArgs` returns `["whatever"]`.

So in your case you should just do this:

```
Prelude> :set args gecode_compile
```