# How can I test a program reading from stdin in GHCi?

Tags: haskell, testing, io, interactive, ghci

My program has a bug I want to see within GHCi:

```
$ ./my-program < ./my-data
Prelude.foldl1: empty list
```

I tried changing `stdin` or `getLine` in GHCi but it doesn't seem to affect the `getLine` my program uses, even if I load afterwards:

```
$ ghci
Prelude> import System.IO
Prelude System.IO> getLine <- fmap hGetLine $ openFile "my-data" ReadMode
:l "my-program.hs"
:main
```

Do I need to rewrite all my IOs to take an explicit handle to be able to test them in GHCi?

Comment: I'm not a bash expert, but I think you might mean `cat my-data | ./my-program`. I think that should work.

Comment: #UUOC Actually, `cat my-data | ./my-program` and `./my-program < ./my-data` are equivalent but for spawning a useless `cat` process… cf. [Stop Piping Cats](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-badunixhabits.html?ca=lnxw01GoodUnixHabits#ten)

Comment: I wonder about the negative votes. Comments as to why would be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try wrapping your program in something like this (tested, working code):

```
import qualified System.IO
import qualified GHC.IO.Handle

filename = "/tmp/myfilename"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      

main = do                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
      h <- System.IO.openFile filename System.IO.ReadMode                                                                                                                                                                                         
      old_stdin <- GHC.IO.Handle.hDuplicate System.IO.stdin                                                                                                                                                                                       
      GHC.IO.Handle.hDuplicateTo h System.IO.stdin                                                                                                                                                                                                
      System.IO.hClose h
      realMain
      GHC.IO.Handle.hDuplicateTo old_stdin System.IO.stdin

realMain = ...
```

It should also be possible to define a user-defined GHCi command that does this for any GHCi command, but I haven't tried yet. See [here](https://gist.github.com/maoe/424018) for someone's .ghci that redirects command's *stdout* with a user-defined `:redir` command.

Comment: `hDuplicateTo h System.IO.stdin`  gets me `getTerminalAttributes: illegal operation (Inappropriate ioctl for device)`

Comment: @Nowhereman I have just tried this and it works for me from ghci (fixed some error in the code, so now it's a complete tested snippet). Are you on Windows per any chance? Did you implement a ghci :redir-style command?

Comment: Your code only works if I replace GHC.Handle by GHC.IO.Handle. Also, it works if I load it as a file but not if I type it in GHCi (I get the same error). I did not try it as a command yet.

Comment: Yes I replaced GHC.Handle in the final version too.

Comment: This also worked for me when I typed a similar definition in ghci

Comment: Just defined `let runit real_main filename = ...` the rest is identical, then call `runit main "myfile.txt"`

Comment: I wonder why this works as a function but not as a ghci command…

Comment: This gives me an error of `Exception: <stdin>: hDuplicate: illegal operation (cannot flush the read buffer: underlying device is not seekable)`

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Works for me with ghc-8.6.5 and 8.8.1 on Ubuntu. Do you have Windows perhaps?

Comment: It seems to be an issue when using `ghcid` - it works correctly with `ghci`.

Answer (score -1):

I think you want:

```
ghci> :set args YOUR_ARG
ghci> main
```

Or

```
ghci> :main YOUR_ARG
```

See here: [How to set a program's command line arguments for GHCi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8867350/how-to-set-a-programs-command-line-arguments-for-ghci#8867385)

Comment: My program doesn't use any arguments, so no.